# Remain in web view using android

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a website of which I have made the mobile version . Now, thing I want is to open the URL in web view and successfully I have done it , next thing is I want that when user login or click any button it should remain in the web view instead of going in the browser. I haven't done this kind on work before so I wonder if it can be done . For example if the website have 4 links so when I click any of the link it should open with in the web view but now it will take it to the browser.

Comment: check wheather you are calling implicit intent ??, if yes please dont call that. your web page will load in web view.

Comment: I am using like the following 

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webView.loadUrl("http://www.aamirarif.com/organizer_json/mobile/");

Comment: @WaleedAhmed Please modify your code as below: `webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); webView.loadUrl("aamirarif.com/organizer_json/mobile/");` and it should work. Please let me know if there are any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you structured your `webView` but if you use the following line after instantiating your `webView`, will resolve your issue.

```
<Your_WebView>.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: I am using like the following 

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webView.loadUrl("http://www.aamirarif.com/organizer_json/mobile/");

Comment: @WaleedAhmed Please modify your code as below: `webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); webView.loadUrl("aamirarif.com/organizer_json/mobile/");` and it should work. Please let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: Thank you it works now my code is 

ebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); 
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
  webView.loadUrl("http://aamirarif.com/tomnjoe/login.php");
 

username is mohsin
password is 123

when you do login in uploadmainlogo option i have given the option to uploading image that is not working on app can you tell me its solution ?

Comment: What is the error are you getting? Please post that as a new question and post `logcat` error messages...

Comment: I have done the tick mark but cant do the up arrow as it says i need 15 more reputations , can you up mark me ?

Answer (score 0):

this will help you:

http://javatechig.com/android/android-webview-example/

> It is an android default behavior, that it opens the links in default
>   android browser when links are clicked from a WebView. If we want to
>   such annoying characteristics, and always open the links in the
>   browser field instead redirected to the default browser, then we have
>   intercept the click events.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;
    private EditText urlEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

        urlEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urlField);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        Button openUrl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goButton);
        openUrl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String url = urlEditText.getText().toString();
                if(validateUrl(url)){
                    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webView.loadUrl(url);
                }
            }
            private boolean validateUrl(String url) {
                return true;
            }
        });    
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.web_view, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```